# inline image transforms

Tags: image-transforms

Is it possible to set an inline image transform's settings from the output of a Matrix block field?

For example

```
{% set transform = {
  mode: 'block.imageMode',
  width: block.imageWidth,
  position: 'block.imageFocus'
} %}
```

Each time I've tried this, the image gives 404. I know the surrounding code works as expected because hard coding the values, the image displays as we'd expect.

This works just fine:

```
{% set transform = {
  mode: 'crop',
  width: 300,
  quality: 70,
  position: 'center-center'
} %}
```

**EDIT:**

Some surrounding code for context

```
{% for image in block.image %}

{% set transform = {
  mode: block.imageMode,
  width: block.imageWidth,
  quality: 70,
  position: block.focalPoint
} %}

<div class="figure  image--{{ block.imagePosition }}">
  <p>
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl(transform) }}" width="{{ image.getWidth(transform) }}" height="{{ image.getHeight(transform) }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
    {% if image.title %}<b class="figure__caption">{{ image.title }}</b>{% endif %}
  </p>
</div>
<!-- // .figure -->

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without the quotes:

```
{% set transform = {
       mode: block.imageMode,
       width: block.imageWidth,
       position: block.imageFocus
   }
%}
```

Comment: negative - even tried putting the quotes into the actual dropdown selector value in the CP. The src of the image is <img src="http://craft.dev/resources/transforms/9?x=JnxyQdEtY" width="300" height="105" alt="WebBanner">

Comment: would it make a difference that the image is also coming from S3?

Comment: Do a `dump(transform)` and see what that outputs.

Comment: http://d.pr/n/19IcA

Comment: bizarre, started working - peculiar

Comment: lol - let's just say I fixed it and call it a day. :)